# Help with hooks and taxonomies: Modifying the posts query in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, post, hook, taxonomy

in wordpress you can do the following:

http://example.com/tag/jazz,blues/ (returns tags page with posts tagged with jazz OR blues)

http://example.com/tag/jazz+blues/ (returns tags page with posts tagged with jazz AND blues)

I want to be able to do the same thing with other taxonomies other than the "tag" taxonomy.

I've created a "music" taxonomy and am trying the following:

http://example.com/music/jazz/ (WORKS)

http://example.com/music/jazz,blues/ (DOES NOT WORK)

http://example.com/music/jazz+blues/ (DOES NOT WORK)

Is there a hook before the query which will allow me to modify the query using $wp_query (which returns info about the current request) ... OR can I hook in before the posts are displayed, requery for new posts using new criteria (would probably only happen on the particular taxonomy page) ??

Comment: This question is a candidate for deletion; the problem was due to another plug-in (see below) and unrelated to Wordpress per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem above was solved by disabling some plugins ... I had a few plugins related to category reordering and exclusions, I think they were interfering in some way.

Answer (score 0):

[Custom Taxonomies?](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-taxonomies/)

Comment: thanks I'm actually using that plugin now, very useful UI for managing both hierarchical and tag based taxonomies

Comment: FYI, I just found out that Custom Taxonomies can, in some cases, break  the WP search in the way that search returns no results. So that plugin itself might be causing issues....

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ElVieejo: this is a 3 year old question, a bad one at that, and it was eventually answered by the questioner himself. Your time is better spent on more important and newer questions....